# How to avoid intersection of elements in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, fill

How can I achieve that the black dots are in front of the fill in the picture below?

[image]

Here is the MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \tikzstyle{point}=[circle,thick,draw=black,fill=black,inner sep=0pt,minimum width=6pt,minimum height=6pt]
            \node (a)[point,label={[label distance=-.6cm]0:$a$}] at (0,0) {};
            \node (b)[point,label={[label distance=0cm]0:$b$}] at (3,0) {};
            \node (c)[point,label={[label distance=.-.5cm]5:$c$}] at (4,3) {};
            \node (d)[point,label={[label distance=-.5cm]5:$d$}] at (1,2) {};
            \draw [fill = gray](a.center) -- (b.center) -- (d.center) -- cycle;
            \draw (b.center) -- (c.center) -- (d.center) -- cycle;
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Draw them in the order you want them displayed.  Just because you *define* the coordinates at the start doesn't mean you have to draw them then.  Indeed, it can make for cleaner picture code to set up all the coordinates at the start as just coordinates and then to do the drawing afterwards.  This gives greater control over things like the order in which things are drawn.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/335249/86}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (a) at (0,0);
\coordinate (b) at (3,0);
\coordinate (c) at (4,3);
\coordinate (d) at (1,2);
\draw [fill=gray](a) -- (b) -- (d) -- cycle;
\draw (b) -- (c) -- (d) -- cycle;
\foreach \coord/\pos in {
  a/left,
  b/right,
  c/right,
  d/left%
} {
  \fill (\coord) circle[radius=3pt];
  \node[\pos=1mm] at (\coord) {\(\coord\)};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: Quad with coordinates]

Answer (score 6):

Here's a third option which requires neither re-ordering your code nor loading an additional library.

This relies on the fact that the black circles are darker than the grey fill. Given that, we can add `blend mode=darken` to the command which adds the fill and the grey will not paint over the darker circles behind.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [
    point/.style={circle,thick,draw=black,fill=black,inner sep=0pt,minimum width=6pt,minimum height=6pt},
  ]
  \node (a) [point, label={[label distance=-.6cm]0:$a$}] at (0,0) {};
  \node (b) [point, label={[label distance=0cm]0:$b$}] at (3,0) {};
  \node (c) [point, label={[label distance=.-.5cm]5:$c$}] at (4,3) {};
  \node (d) [point, label={[label distance=-.5cm]5:$d$}] at (1,2) {};
  \draw [blend mode=darken, fill = gray] (a.center) -- (b.center) -- (d.center) -- cycle;
  \draw (b.center) -- (c.center) -- (d.center) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: tweaking apparent order with a <code>blend mode</code>]

Answer (score 5):

You can use the backgrounds library to refer to a layer behind the dots.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            [ point/.style={circle,thick,draw=black,fill=black,inner sep=0pt,minimum width=6pt,minimum height=6pt}, ]
            \node (a)[point,label={[label distance=-.6cm]0:$a$}] at (0,0) {};
            \node (b)[point,label={[label distance=0cm]0:$b$}] at (3,0) {};
            \node (c)[point,label={[label distance=.-.5cm]5:$c$}] at (4,3) {};
            \node (d)[point,label={[label distance=-.5cm]5:$d$}] at (1,2) {};
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
            \draw [fill = gray](a.center) -- (b.center) -- (d.center) -- cycle;
            \draw (b.center) -- (c.center) -- (d.center) -- cycle;
\end{scope}
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\tikzstyle` is deprecated.

Comment: @cfr hey that bit's just copied from the question!, at least I answered with some tikz, not my habitual picture mode:-)

Comment: Would you say that about an answer which replicated use of `\rm` or something in a LaTeX document? ;-)

Comment: @cfr I'd say it was lovely, of course!

Comment: `[
    point/.style={circle,thick,draw=black,fill=black,inner sep=0pt,minimum width=6pt,minimum height=6pt},
  ]` If you change it, I can upvote your answer ;).

Comment: @cfr, thanks I had just been wondering if it was ethical to steal that line from your answer:-)

Comment: :-) and something